# How do I assign methods to a specific parameter using PIVOT in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, pivot

We're working on producing our data as a relational database/set and as a row-column dataset (so that the users of the data can use which format suits them best). Here's a simplified table of our data:

```
drop table parameter_test;
create table parameter_test
 (
  site_id       VARCHAR(30),
  parameter     VARCHAR(30),
  value         NUMBER,
  method        VARCHAR(30)
);

insert into parameter_test values ('site1', 'ANC', 10.1,'Gran 1952');
insert into parameter_test values('site2', 'ANC', 21.8, 'Gran 1952');
insert into parameter_test values('site1', 'NO3', 2.1, 'EPA 1983');
insert into parameter_test values('site2', 'NO3', 7.2, 'EPA 1983');
```

I know how to pivot for the values, but this doesn't put the method into a specific parameter_column (ANC_method or NO3 method):

```
drop table parameter_pivot_test;
create table parameter_pivot_test
AS
(select * from (select site_id, parameter_number, parameter
   from parameter_test) 
   pivot (sum(parameter_number) for parameter in (
'ANC'   ANC,
'NO3'   NO3
)))
;
```

But I want to get the following table:

```
drop table parameter_pivot;
create table parameter_pivot
 (
  site_id       VARCHAR(30),
  ANC           NUMBER,
  NO3           NUMBER,
  ANC_method    VARCHAR(30),
  NO3_method    VARCHAR(30)
);

insert into parameter_pivot values ('site1', 10.1, 2.1, 'Gran 1952', 'EPA 1983');
insert into parameter_pivot values ('site2', 21.8, 7.2, 'Gran 1952', 'EPA 1983');
```

How do I get the specific methods to attach to the specific parameter as a new column? I feel like it might be some sort of group by statement, but not sure where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: For starters, I assume when you say "parameter_number", you mean "value" (there is no column named parameter_number in your table. Second, is the (parameter, method) pair the same across all sites? Is "Gran 1952" always the method used with ANC? If so, you might be in for a bit of normalization. If not, how would you want to handle it? Get sums per pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    site_id,
    max(case when parameter = 'ANC' then value end) anc,
    max(case when parameter = 'NO3' then value end) no3,
    max(case when parameter = 'ANC' then method end) anc_method,
    max(case when parameter = 'NO3' then method end) no3_method
from parameter_pivot
group by side_id
```

This pivots the data over a *fixed* list of columns. If you want a dynamic pivot, then you need dynamic SQL, which is a different beast.

Comment: The first two aggregates should be SUM's, not MAX's

Comment: @downernn: maybe. It's hard to tell for sure. OP showed no parameter/value duplicate in their sample data, and did not specify how to handle such case.

Comment: Correct, but OP did use `sum(parameter_number) for ...` in their pivot definition. By that I assume (and I think so did you), that they meant `sum(value) for ...`. There is no column named "parameter_number" (their code throws an error) and the numbers showed in the example are the same as in the "value" column. So I'm pretty sure they meant to do a sum on the "value" column.

Comment: In this sample data, there is no parameter/value duplicate. And in the full dataset, I will be grouping by site_id, date, and another column to yield a unique set of variables that will only have one value per unique combination. So either sum or max will work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it with a full outer join.

I don't think it's possible with a pivot if there are going to be multiple methods for the same parameter.

```
drop table parameter_pivot_test;
create table parameter_pivot_test
AS
(select coalesce(anc_site, no3_site) as site_id, anc, no3, anc_method, mo3_method from
(select site_id as anc_site, value as anc, method as anc_method from parameter_test where parameter = 'ANC') anc
FULL OUTER JOIN
(select site_id as no3_site, value as no3, method as no3_method from parameter_test where parameter = 'NO3') no3
ON anc.anc_site = no3.no3_site
)
;
```

Comment: This works, but is a bit slow (takes 15+ seconds for those 2 variables (ANC. NO3). I have 12 or so other variables that would need to be added.

Comment: No problem, having seen GMB's answer I would recommend that

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PIVOT` and aggregate on the `value` and `method` columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE parameter_pivot_test AS
SELECT site_id,
       anc_value AS anc,
       no3_value AS noc,
       anc_method,
       no3_method
FROM   parameter_test
PIVOT (
  SUM( value ) AS value,
  MAX( method ) AS method
  FOR parameter IN (
   'ANC' AS ANC,
   'NO3' AS NO3
  )
);
```

Which for your test data:

```sql
create table parameter_test
 (
  site_id       VARCHAR(30),
  parameter     VARCHAR(30),
  value         NUMBER,
  method        VARCHAR(30)
);

insert into parameter_test ( site_id, parameter, value, method )
SELECT 'site1', 'ANC', 10.1,'Gran 1952' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'site2', 'ANC', 21.8, 'Gran 1952' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'site1', 'NO3', 2.1, 'EPA 1983' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'site2', 'NO3', 7.2, 'EPA 1983' FROM DUAL;
```

Gives the output:

```sql
SELECT * FROM parameter_pivot_test;
```

> ```
> SITE_ID |  ANC | NOC | ANC_METHOD | NO3_METHOD
> :------ | ---: | --: | :--------- | :---------
> site2   | 21.8 | 7.2 | Gran 1952  | EPA 1983  
> site1   | 10.1 | 2.1 | Gran 1952  | EPA 1983
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=69633364c36fb1834b74c689e13d1f6d)*

Comment: Couldn't quite get this to work on my full dataset, but I imagine that it has something to do with having multiple parameters (10 others plus ANC and NO3). Might take a second look at it when I get some more time.